# Can we use scroll event for div?

Tags: jquery

I am triggering the scrollbar event in the div. It is not triggered.

**My scenario:**

When scroll to the down bottom want to alert the user.
I am sharing the sample code.

```
<div class="screen">
    <div class="main_wrap" id="Main">
       <div class="sub-wrap">
            <div class="title">
            </div>
            <div class="desc">
            </div>
        </div>
 <div class="sub-wrap">
            <div class="title">
            </div>
            <div class="desc">
            </div>
        </div>
 <div class="sub-wrap">
            <div class="title">
            </div>
            <div class="desc">
            </div>
        </div> <div class="sub-wrap">
            <div class="title">
            </div>
            <div class="desc">
            </div>
        </div> <div class="sub-wrap">
            <div class="title">
            </div>
            <div class="desc">
            </div>
        </div>
 <div class="sub-wrap">
            <div class="title">
            </div>
            <div class="desc">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried like this.

```
    $('#Main').bind('scroll', function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= this.scrollHeight) {
            ajaxPost.GetCommunityInfoList();
        }
    });
```

Suggest me with ideas.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Its HTML where is the js?

Answer (score 0):

check with this below code it may help you....

```js
$('.screen').bind('scroll', function(){
  if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight()>=$(this)[0].scrollHeight)
  {
    alert('end reached');
  }
});
```

```css
.screen{
  height : 400px;
  background : black;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
#Main{
  height : 600px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="screen">
  <div class="main_wrap" id="Main">
    <div class="sub-wrap">
      <div class="title">
      </div>
      <div class="desc">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-wrap">
      <div class="title">
      </div>
      <div class="desc">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-wrap">
      <div class="title">
      </div>
      <div class="desc">
      </div>
    </div> <div class="sub-wrap">
    <div class="title">
    </div>
    <div class="desc">
    </div>
    </div> <div class="sub-wrap">
    <div class="title">
    </div>
    <div class="desc">
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-wrap">
      <div class="title">
      </div>
      <div class="desc">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can Do it. Consider my example

[image: Trigger the handler]

The scroll event handler can be bound to this element:

```
$( "#target" ).scroll(function() {
$( "#log" ).append( "<div>Handler for .scroll() called.</div>" );
});
```

Now when the user scrolls the text up or down, one or more messages are appended to :
Handler for .scroll() called.
To trigger the event manually, apply .scroll() without an argument

```
$( "#other" ).click(function() {
$( "#target" ).scroll();
});
```

After this code executes, clicks on Trigger the handler will also append the message.

A scroll event is sent whenever the element's scroll position changes, regardless of the cause. A mouse click or drag on the scroll bar, dragging inside the element, pressing the arrow keys, or using the mouse's scroll wheel could cause this event.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
    function div_scroll(e) { var mydiv = $(e.currentTarget);
     if(mydiv[0].scrollHeight - mydiv.scrollTop() == mydiv.outerHeight())
 alert('at bottom');
    }

    $(function () { $('#main').bind('scroll', div_scroll); });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use .scroll() and .scrollTop for this

Check this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wrajesh/xzvh9ewf/2/)

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
    alert("bottom!");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="screen">
  <div class="main_wrap" id="Main">
    <div class="sub-wrap">
      <div class="title">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
      </div>
      <div class="desc">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque fringilla vel,
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-wrap">
      <div class="title">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
      </div>
      <div class="desc">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque fringilla vel,
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-wrap">
      <div class="title">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
      </div>
      <div class="desc">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque fringilla vel,
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-wrap">
      <div class="title">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
      </div>
      <div class="desc">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque fringilla vel,
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-wrap">
      <div class="title">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
      </div>
      <div class="desc">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque fringilla vel,
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-wrap">
      <div class="title">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
      </div>
      <div class="desc">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque fringilla vel,
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-wrap">
      <div class="title">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
      </div>
      <div class="desc">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque fringilla vel,
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-wrap">
      <div class="title">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
      </div>
      <div class="desc">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque fringilla vel,
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-wrap">
      <div class="title">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
      </div>
      <div class="desc">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque fringilla vel,
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-wrap">
      <div class="title">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
      </div>
      <div class="desc">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque fringilla vel,
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-wrap">
      <div class="title">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
      </div>
      <div class="desc">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque fringilla vel,
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-wrap">
      <div class="title">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
      </div>
      <div class="desc">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque fringilla vel,
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-wrap">
      <div class="title">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
      </div>
      <div class="desc">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque fringilla vel,
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-wrap">
      <div class="title">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
      </div>
      <div class="desc">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque fringilla vel,
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```